# Issue with Bitcoin Price Retrieval in Widget Class - Updating Price on Button Click

Tags: c++, qt, button, click, fetch-api

I hope you are doing well. I am currently facing an issue related to the retrieval of the Bitcoin price in my Qt application. I have implemented a functionality to fetch the Bitcoin price from an API, and it works fine when called during the initialization of the Widget class in the Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) constructor. However, I'm experiencing difficulties when trying to fetch and update the Bitcoin price upon clicking a button.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code (the code that updates price when app opens) :

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "./ui_widget.h"
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QDebug>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/BTC.json")));

    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [this, reply]() {
        if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
            QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
            QJsonDocument jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data);

            QJsonObject jsonObj = jsonDoc.object();
            QJsonObject bpiObj = jsonObj["bpi"].toObject();
            QJsonObject usdObj = bpiObj["USD"].toObject();
            double bitcoinValue = usdObj["rate_float"].toDouble();

            // Przypisz wartość bitcoina do zmiennej w klasie Widget
            this->bitcoinValue_ = bitcoinValue;

            // Możesz tutaj umieścić kod, który używa wartości bitcoina

        } else {
            qDebug() << "Error occurred while fetching Bitcoin value: " << reply->errorString();
        }

        reply->deleteLater();
    });
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::on_pushButton_pressed()
{
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(this->bitcoinValue_) + "$");
}


void Widget::on_pushButton_released()
{
    ui->label->setText("");
}
```

I would like to update the Bitcoin price every time the button is clicked. I've tried moving the code block responsible for fetching the price to the on_pushButton_Pressed slot function, but it doesn't update the price. In fact, it seems to not be working at all. The value of the Bitcoin price is not updated or fetched correctly.

I would greatly appreciate your help in understanding how to correctly update the Bitcoin price on each button click. Is there a specific approach or modification to the code that I need to implement in order to achieve this functionality?

Thank you in advance for your assistance and guidance.

I tried using the code above.

Comment: Does the code successfully fetch the bitcoin price on the initialization of `Widget`?

Comment: I only see the one call to get(), in the creation of reply. Are you expecting subsequent get() calls to get updated information from the site?

Comment: Yes, THE code successfully fetch the bitcoin price on the initialozation of widget. 

I’m exepecting that, everytime i click a button a variable bitcoinvalue_ updates.